# How to convert and calculate value from string to number after of $http.post in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how convert and calculate string, in this case i call an ajax "order/list" using $http.post to get a list like that, it contains 3 objects:

```
{
"orders":[
    {
        "id_order":"206",
        "shipping":"100.00",
        "tax":"35.00"
    },
    {
        "id_order":"205",
        "shipping":"160.00",
        "tax":"16.00"
    },
    {
        "id_order":"204",
        "shipping":"100.00",
        "tax":"16.00"
    }

]
}
```

Tax is a percentage,
then I use ng-repeat to display list of order:

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <td>{{order.id_order}}</td>
    <td>$ {{(order.shipping * (order.tax/100) ) + order.shipping }}</td>
</tr>
```

You see {{(order.shipping * (order.tax/100) ) + order.shipping }} that I need to convert them as number and calculate, for example, shipping is 100.00 and tax is 16.00, excepted result would be 116.00, not 16100.00

Comment: your properties are strings, not numbers, so you can't do math using them

Comment: Claies's comment is correct. AngularJS is very sensitive to this and will not perform calculations if the properties contain string instead of numbers. It would be helpful to know where you are getting this data from because it's better to get the JSON correctly from the source rather than converting the data in Javascript. For example, if it's PHP you can force the json_encode to use the correct data types.

Comment: @Claies  You didn't read at all like I asked "how to convert ... as number from string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to have a look here
https://jsfiddle.net/z5gnhzt2/

```
 $scope.calculate = function(shipping, tax){
        return parseFloat(shipping) * parseFloat(tax)/100 + parseFloat(shipping);
    };

 <td>$ {{calculate(order.shipping, order.tax)}}</td>
```

Comment: This is definetly good answer, calculate function would be flexible solution that can place anywhere, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you realy want to do the calculation in the view you could use the "number filter"

```
{{ (order.shipping | number) * (order.tax | number)/100 }}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/kde0mxpe/4/

However, I would advise to do these calculations in your controller and keep the view clean of this logic.

```
angular.forEach($scope.orders, function(order) {
        order.shippingIncTax = parseInt(order.shipping)*(parseInt(order.tax)/100);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a middle function, like in this little example :

```
$scope.test = [
  { a : '23', b : '45' },
  { a : '3', b : '4' }    
]

$scope.doCalc = function(a,b) {
  return parseInt(a)*parseInt(b);
}
```

markup :

```
<table> 
  <thead>
    <tr><th>calc</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in test">
      <td>
        {{ doCalc(c.a, c.b) }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/kIXOQ7B3OMrdypqaTz39?p=preview**

Answer (score 2):

The math could be simplified to:

```
{{order.shipping * (1 + order.tax / 100) | currency}}
```

And that avoids the problem of the *addition* of strings.

Here is **[the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/cb5qwadt/6/)**

---

As a side note, I would personally advise to work on the REST Api so as to get numbers instead of strings. We see too much patches or reformat on the client-side, when it can be corrected at the source.

Comment: That's hacky, I've used {{order.shipping * (order.tax / 10) + ".00"}}  but I wouldn't use :P

Comment: By the way you could use the `currency` filter.

Comment: about ".00" is used for decimals as cents, it's for display, there no reason to use cents.

Comment: Decimals, and also currency symbol, should be handled by the currency filter. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/cb5qwadt/2/)

Comment: Thanks for idea, I didn't know about Currency filter

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more idiomatic AngularJS answer. In the meantime, have a look at [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), because your JSON object is returning strings (they are double-quoted) instead of numeric values:

```
var shipping = "100.00";
var tax = "16.00";

(parseFloat(shipping) * (parseFloat(tax)/100) ) + parseFloat(shipping);
// 116
```

Or in Angular:

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <td>{{order.id_order}}</td>
    <td>$ {{(parseFloat(order.shipping) * (parseFloat(order.tax)/100) ) + parseFloat(order.shipping) }}</td>
</tr>
```

If you are in a position to control the API from which you retrieve the JSON data, you may want to consider outputting numeric values (don't quote them).

Also note that `parseFloat()` will strip trailing decimal zeros (which are only used to represent scientific precision):

```
> tax = "16.00";
'16.00'
> parseFloat(tax);
16
> tax = "16.0001";
'16.0001'
> parseFloat(tax);
16.0001
```

Comment: But how do you get 2 variables as shipping and tax from JSON data as 3 objects and render literally {{orders.calculatedTax}}

This is angular.js, not as Javascript solution

Comment: @Ivan As I showed in my first example, you wrap `parseFloat()` around your JSON values... I updated my answer. Your statement that this is AngularJS but not JavaScript is somewhat puzzling, though.

Comment: Your updated answer returned as "null" AngularJS doesn't work JS expression inside of {{ }}

Answer (score 1):

How did you get the value of 16100.00 if you havn´t allready converted them to numbers?

```
(order.shipping * (order.tax/100)) + order.shipping
```

If converting to numbers is the problem, you can try to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398319/how-can-i-parse-string-to-int-in-the-angular-expression).

Comment: Obviously, it's string like "200" and "300" it can be added as "200300", if were numbers not as string, it would be 500

Comment: Shouldn´t that be something like... "16.00100.00" then? ;)

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I make typos