# Convert numeric string to number in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to compare angular 2 expressions. I got array of data in numeric string from my database i need to convert this to number before give a condition with ngClass for styling. how can i convert this type. any idea?

```
  <td [ngClass]= "{'positive': gbh.Last > 0, 'negative': gbh.Last < 0}"> {{gbh.Last}} </td>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398319/how-can-i-parse-string-to-int-in-an-angular-expression

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now ... but does this work? +gbh.Last > 0

Comment: if array returns number it works exactly as i shown above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not convert your numeric string to number inside the Angular expression.

The best practice will be to define a method in your controller which will solve your expression by using '[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseInt)'

```
  function isPositive (x: String, y: number): boolean {
      return (parseInt(x, 10) < y);
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

This answer is the typescript way: 
[so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36134133/2945345)

```
Number('1234') // 1234
Number('9BX9') // NaN
```

The other answer looks like it would be for int not numbers. You are better off using the plus symbol.

```
var x = "32";
var y = +x; // y: number
```

Ref [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14668510/2945345):

Comment: Yes those are all valid ways to convert to number in JS and TypeScript, however the question asked about converting to number _within expressions in Angular template HTML_.  Your answer makes no mention of this.  It's worth noting that expression syntax for Angular templates is very limited, and symbols such as `Number` and `var` are not allowed.

Comment: @jcairney `Number` and `var` obviously will not work inside template. but that `+` works in template..