# Why does arr.map(parseInt) not work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, parseint

I feel like I'm doing some noobish overlooking of things. Can anyone help me understand why the following doesn't work

```
["1.1", "2.2", "3.3"].map(parseInt);
//=> [1, NaN, NaN]
```

This works though ???

```
["1.1", "2.2", "3.3"].map(function(num) {
  return parseInt(num);
});
//=> [1, 2, 3]
```

This seems to work too

```
["1.1", "2.2", "3.3"].map(Number);
//=> [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]
```

Comment: Note `["1.1", "1.1", "1.1", "2.2", "3.3"].map(parseInt);` → `[1, NaN, 1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` passes more than one arguments to the callback. In particular the second argument it passes is the index of the element being processed.

`parseInt` accepts more than one argument. In particular the second argument it accepts is the base of the numeric system you are converting from.

When the second element is processed you are calling `parseInt("2.2", 1)`, and since `2` is not a valid digit in base 1 the result is `NaN`.

If you declare a "wrapper" callback around `parseInt` then these additional arguments are lost and everything seems to work correctly, although [you should *always* pass the second argument to `parseInt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior).

Comment: Ah, I knew it was noobish overlooking! Thanks for the insight. So is there any harm in me using `.map(Number)` then?

Comment: @naomik: No, `Number` is fine.

Comment: @naomik `.map(parseFloat)` works too.

Comment: @naomik `["1.1", "2.2", "3.3"].map(Math.floor)` may do what you were originally intending with `parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. The float is an okay solution too. If I needed to force an int, `Math.floor` looks like a good function to use :)