# How to add input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have 4 text boxes namely `customer_phy_tot`, `customer_che_tot`, `customer_bio_tot`. I'm trying to add and display all 3 input boxes values to a 4th input, `customer_pcb_tot`.

```
customer_bio_obt.blur(function(){
    var customer_pcb_tot = isNaN(parseInt($("#customer_phy_tot").val() + $("#customer_che_tot").val() + $("#customer_bio_tot").val())) ? 0 :( $("#customer_phy_tot").val() + $("#customer_che_tot").val() + $("#customer_bio_tot").val())
    $("#customer_pcb_tot").val(customer_pcb_tot);
});
```

The problem is instead of adding my code is treating it as a string. Suppose I have values `10`, `15` and `5` respectively. It's supposed to display `30` in the 4th box but in my case it is showing `10155`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: use parseInt for separate values not for all `val() + val()`

Comment: `total = (parseInt($("#somtthing").val()) || 0) + ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `parseInt()` already, but you need to use it on the string values returned by each individual `val()` call. Also note that your use of a ternary expression is redundant. Try this:

```
customer_bio_obt.blur(function() {
    var customer_pcb_tot = parseInt($("#customer_phy_tot").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#customer_che_tot").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#customer_bio_tot").val(), 10);
    $("#customer_pcb_tot").val(customer_pcb_tot || 0);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `parseInt()` function to do this :)

You have to use it to each of your values do make it works.

As @Jamie R Rytlewski said :

> Make sure you use the radix value also. parseInt(string, radix);

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: But make sure you use the radix value also. parseInt(string, radix); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: radix is 10 by default

Comment: It's still considered best practice to always include it. From MDN: `Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior has details on why to always include it as well

Comment: but anyway, from MDN references: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix says (`in 10-11`) radix should be 10 by default,

Comment: It will be 10 by default... unless someone enters a string where the leading character is a zero, in which it goes to base 8

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan does it depend on user browser?

Comment: No as it's how the javascript standard is written, not any specific browser implementation.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it looks like it is not a problem for modern browsers. as at http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256C85006A6604 ( from links above) everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can parseInt() in each val() that you ask.
Or multiply each one for 1 before sum it.

var customer_pcb_tot= isNaN(parseInt($("#customer_phy_tot").val() + $("#customer_che_tot").val() + $("#customer_bio_tot").val())) ? 0 :( $("#customer_phy_tot").val()*1 + $("#customer_che_tot").val()*1 + $("#customer_bio_tot").val()*1)