# Console.log output in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why do `console.log(00);` and `console.log(01);` print 0 & 1 in the browser console and not 00 & 01?

```
console.log(00); // prints 0;
console.log(01); // prints 1;
console.log(011); // prints 9;
console.log(0111); // prints 73;
```

Comment: Why *would* it print `00`?

Comment: I'm curious why, in your description, you only ask about 00 and 01, given that the behaviour of the 011 and 0111 examples is more interesting...

Comment: @nnnnnn want to know about the other examples as well, just to start the context of my question i mentioned 00 & 01

Comment: Behaviour of 011 and 0111 is a huge hint here :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I work around JavaScript's parseInt octal behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior)

Comment: What's the idea with this equals sign? Not only doesn't make sense, but also completely confusing.

Comment: @Matsemann Not really a dupe. Although related, this is about integer literals not about `parseInt`

Answer (score 23):

> Never write a number with a leading zero (like 07).
>   Some JavaScript versions interpret numbers as octal if they are written with a leading zero.

That is because JavaScript treats leading 0 as octal number and that is why you are getting the octal number(base 8).

You could use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with radix to eliminate these kind of issues.

And the reason why console.log treats the input as octal is, by default console.log calls `valueOf` method of input. If it doesn't returns anything it will call `toString` method.

And the `valueOf` method returns values like below:

```
00.valueOf()   // 0
01.valueOf()   // 1
011.valueOf()  // 9
0111.valueOf() // 73
```

**Reference:-** http://javascript.info/tutorial/object-conversion

For your reference I've added the number system table

### Number System table

[image: Number System]

Comment: OK, but that doesn't really explain the output not having the leading zeros.

Answer (score 12):

**Evaluating**

When executing `console.log(stuff)`, before printing, `stuff` is evaluated to see what is to be printed. This is why `console.log(3+2)` prints `5` and not `3+2`. This has nothing to do with `console.log` in particular, the evaluation is done before the execution of `console.log`. Any function would behave the same way, it would be passed the evaluated `5` as parameter and not the initial `3+2`

**Parsing**

Even before evaluating, there is another factor at play: parsing. Parsing is the first step of interpreting the source code and it refers to analysing the characters in the source code to figure out what logical constructs (tokens) they refer to.

The tricky bit here is that numbers can be written in a [few ways](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf#page=167):

- `1`, `15`  - numbers written in decimal (base 10)
- `01`, `017` - numbers written in octal (base 8)
- `0b1`, `0b1111` - numbers written in binary (base 2)
- `0x1`, `0xE` - numbers written in hexadecimal (base 16)

All of these refer to the same 2 numbers - 1 and 15, but they are different graphical representations the same way you would consider `6` and `0000006` the same number.

Once the source code is parsed, the characters written in the source code are "replaced" by the actual number they represent. This means that even before the Javascript engine knows it has to do some printing the characters you have written are gone and what remains are the actual numbers you have referenced.

**Annex B**

While the main Javascript spec considers octal numbers only those starting with `0o`, the [legacy syntax](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf#page=557) considers octal numbers those starting with `0`.

Answer (score 6):

leading zero in console making it to base of 8.

```
console.log(00)=0
console.log(01)=1
console.log(011)=9 //0+8+1
console.log(0111)=73 //0+64+8+1
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write console.log(00), the argument 00 is interpreted as number and so 0 is printed. On the other hand if you write console.log("00") 00 is interpreted as a string and 00 is printed.

Comment: The question becomes more interesting when you look at the last two examples in the question, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Cause console.log always shows in DEC format. For example: 011 is 11 in OCT, and 9 in DEC.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on it and found this solution.

Point 1 - If any number leading with zero will not always be considered as the decimal.

point 2 - A number leading with zero and do not contain 8 or 9 in remaining number will be considered as octal and converted to decimal when printing its value.

point 3 - A number leading with zero and contains 8 or 9 in remaining number will be considered as decimal value.

point 4 - 00 to 07 will not be converted to decimal as they are already in decimal.

```
var a = 07
console.log(a)  //// 7

var a = 08
console.log(a)  //// 8

var a = 016
console.log(a) //////14

var a = 018
console.log(a) //////18

var a = 078
console.log(a) //////78

var a = 077
console.log(a)  ////////63

var a = 096
console.log(a) /////96
```