# console.log weird behaviour with numbers

Tags: javascript

`console.log(01)` results in `1`

But

`console.log(011)` results in `9`

Can someone explain how `console.log` works with such numbers?

Comment: @AvinashMahlawat this isn't C/C++, though. Sure, it's the same concept in this case but it's not a clear dupe.

Comment: @VLAZ this is related to octal notation, not language specific.So, i am sure it is an answer of your question.

Comment: @AvinashMahlawat yet this notation is deprecated in JavaScript and shouldn't be relied on. It's not exactly language agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about console.log, a number that starts with 0 is [octal notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571758/console-log-output-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(+"011") // if you use like this it will work
```

`011` is an octal value and its decimal equivalent is 9. Preceding integer literal with 0 indicates octal value.