# Why does "console.log(parseInt(0o22,8))" display "1"

Tags: javascript, parseint

Why does `console.log(parseInt(0o22,8))` output `1`?

Comment: You don't need to repeat your question three times :)

Answer (score 10):

`0oNNN` is ECMAScript 2015 syntax for literal octal numbers.

`0o22` is `18` in decimal. `parseInt` needs a *string*, so this integer `18` is coerced to the decimal string `'18'` by `parseInt`. And since `8` is not a valid digit in base-8, `parseInt` bails out after the first digit and returns 1.

From MDN documentation for [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description):

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. `parseInt` truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

---

See also: [How do I work around JavaScript's parseInt octal behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior)