# Getting NaN error while using parseInt function

Tags: google-apps-script, numbers

I am getting Nan error when I am using parseInt with date strings.
I am getting finalRelease and Original Release value in form of string. I am splitting the value and try to access using index. I am getting correct month in case of finalMonth but it is showing Nan in case of originalMonth.

```
finalRelease = "2017-07-20"
originalRelease = "2017-08-09"
if(finalRelease!=null && originalRelease!=null)  {
      var finalDate = finalRelease.split('-');
      var originalDate = originalRelease.split('-');
      var finalMonth = parseInt(finalDate[1])-1;
      var originalMonth = parseInt(originalDate[1])-1;
```

Comment: This seems to work as expected. Where are you getting the error?

Comment: for the originalMonth , I am getting NaN

Comment: I ran it in my browser console, It gives me answer as 7. No issues.

Comment: Same here, works for me

Comment: for final month it is showing correct 7 but for original Month it is showing NaN

Comment: I'm not familiar with `google-apps-script` but I think you should use console.log to log the value `originalDate` to check if it is in a correct format

Comment: I used that and it is showing NaN for originalMonth value while finalMonth value is coming correct

Comment: Your code could be simplified to one line: `Logger.log(parseInt("08"));` Please read about [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `parseInt("08")` returns NaN in Google Apps Script. This is because GAS, as old versions of JavaScript, [consider the leading 0 as a sign of octal integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior). The remedy is simple:

**Always include the radix (usually 10) with parseInt.**

Use:

```
parseInt("08", 10): 
parseInt(originalDate[1], 10) - 1;
```

Do not use:

```
parseInt("08"): 
parseInt(originalDate[1]) - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another shorter method using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#convert_numeric_strings_and_null_to_numbers) constructor:

```
var num = Number("08"); // 8.0
```